# How to filter data with sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Trying to filter data with sequelize but it seems doesn't work

I have in my model `tags` which have following data `tags: [{id: 1, name: 'Hey'}]`. So i'm trying to get all records from this model where `tags` match `tags` what came from request. ( They have similar data `tags: [{id: 1, name: 'Hey'}]`. But i have all records -> should only one

```
where: {
  tags: {
    $in: req.body.tags
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to paas an array of tags in the `$in` like this `$in : ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']`

Comment: @SKJajoriya, doesn't work getting error about [object Object]

Comment: Can you show me your tags comes from the request that you pass in the query ?

Answer (score 4):

For **$in** condition your tags should be **array of values**, not **array of objects**.

Wrong:

```
tags: [{id: 1, name: 'work'}, {id: 2, name: 'party'}, ... ]
```

Correct:

```
// tags contains name|title of tags. now this is your choice.
tags: ['work', 'party', 'whatever', ...]

// tags contains id's of tags. for this you should change your where condition.
tags: [1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Example:

```
const tagsFromRequest = [{ id: 1, name: 'work' }, { id: 2, name: 'party' }];

const tagsIds = tagsFromRequest.map(tag => tag.id);
const tagsNames = tagsFromRequest.map(tag => tag.name);

const tagsByIds = await DB.tag.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      $in: tagsIds,
    },
  },
});

const tagsByNames = await DB.tag.findAll({
  where: {
    name: {
      $in: tagsNames,
    },
  },
});
```